# Can I work for conventional bank in an organisation

Tags: banking

Assalamualaikum, I just want to know about can we work in conventional bank in an organisation where we have to work as fraud risk analyst where customers has file a complaint about fraud has happened to his her bank account then we have to do a research of fraud which is happened in the customer account and here we are not dealing any interest based transaction just we research the details and updating to the customer this transaction which was happened through your account is fraud. If it was a customers fault then customer have to bare his/her loss of the transaction or due to some technical issue or other things where customer fault is not there then we just update the details to customer it's not your fault then bank reverse the loss amount to customers account.

Answer (score 0):

**According to some sources, working in a conventional bank is generally considered Haram(forbidden) for Muslims, as it involves dealing with interest(Riba), which is prohibited in Islam.**

However, some scholars have given exceptions or concessions for certain situations, such as when there is no alternative or when the job does not directly involve interest transactions.

But as a fraud risk analyst, your job is to prevent, detect, and investigate fraud committed against the bank or its customers . You are not directly involved in interest transactions, but you are **indirectly** supporting the bank's operations and profits, which are based on interest. Therefore, your job might fall into a **gray area**, where **some scholars might consider it permissible, while others might consider it impermissible.**

*It is better seek guidance from knowledgeable Islamic scholars or authorities who can provide a more nuanced understanding based on individual circumstances and the specifics of the job role within the conventional banking framework.*